# MySQL table join in database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to know mysql how can I form a new table to show the data i want?

> Current having Purchase table and Product table

My Product table:

```
=====Product=====
field productID
field category
field brand
field name
field createtime
```

My Purchase table:

```
=====Purchase=====
field UID 
field productID 
field username
field email
field purchaseDate
```

The result table I wish to get:

```
=====OrderList=====
field UID 
field productID
field category
field brand
field name 
field username
field email
field purchaseDate
```

**My doubt, will the mysql OrderList table get automatic update in database once new record insert in Purchase table?**

> below is the example method do this solve my problem?

```
SELECT Purchase.UID, Purchase.productID, Product.category, Product.brand,
 Product.name, Purchase.username, Purchase.email, Purchase.purchaseDate
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Purchase
ON Product.productID=Purchase.productID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "VIEW", for example:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderList
AS
     SELECT Purchase.UID,
            Purchase.productID,
            Product.category,
            Product.brand,
            Product.name,
            Purchase.username,
            Purchase.email,
            Purchase.purchaseDate
       FROM   Product, Purchase
       WHERE  Product.productID = Purchase.productID
   ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName
```

Comment: I'm having problem with this 

>`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Product LEFT JOIN Purchase ON Product.productID = Purchase.productID'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want automatic updating of your OrderList table, then you will need to create a view, rather than a static table:

```
create or replace view OrderList as
    SELECT Purchase.UID, Purchase.productID, Product.category, Product.brand,
 Product.name, Purchase.username, Purchase.email, Purchase.purchaseDate
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Purchase
ON Product.productID=Purchase.productID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```